# Как подвинуть ось Оу в JFreeChart

Tags: java, javafx, swing

Подскажите пожалуйста, как подвинуть ось Oy вправо и добавить отрицание к Ox?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JFreeChart chart = ...
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
plot.getDomainAxis().setRange(-50, 50); // X
plot.getRangeAxis().setRange(-10, 10); // Y
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.